# Choosing the guest user for a channel form

Tags: ee2, safecracker, channel

I've gone through these

http://dotmeta.com/expressionengine/guide/ee-2101/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html

http://dotmeta.com/expressionengine/guide/ee-2101/add-ons/channel/channel_form/examples.html

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_form/index.html

And i don't see a way to tell the {exp:channel:form ...} which Guest user account to use when creating a new entry.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...
Admin > Channel Administration >> Channel Form